# My React Component doesn't seem to re-render

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I tried to refactor some React code and store the state of displays as an object, but now the state doesn't seem to update.
I have

```
let initialDisplay = {"javascript": true,"typescript": false}
const [displays, setDisplays] = useState(initialDisplay);
    
const setDisplay = (name:language|tool, show:boolean) => {
    let newDisplays = displays;
    newDisplays[name] = show;
    setDisplays(newDisplays);
    console.log(displays);
}
```

, an img with

```
onMouseOver={() => setDisplay(name,true)} onMouseOut={() => setDisplay(name, false)}
```

, and

```
<TechDropdown open={displays.javascript} tech={"javascript"}/>
<TechDropdown open={displays.typescript} tech={"typescript"}/>
```

^Those components return this:

```
<SlideDown>
    {props.open ? dropDownContent : null}
</SlideDown>
```

where dropDownContent is basically just the name and an image

It properly console.logs an updated `displays` object, but the TechDropdown component doesn't re-render the changes. Any thoughts?

(My theory: Am I changing the displays object manually with a shallow copy, then when I call setDisplays, there is no change? I'm not sure, let me know.)

Comment: To be exact `let newDisplays = displays;` isn't a shallow copy, it's just pointing that variable at the original object. A standard way to shallow copy would be: `let newDisplays = {...displays};`

Comment: Can you post the entire component? It's hard to tell how you have things organized from what you've posted

Comment: @DBS I tried the spread syntax and it was very buggy, it could at least then change from false to true but it would render slowly

Comment: @BrendanBond I updated the post - SlideDown is a react library `react-slidedown`